# scala Stream processing, counting the occurences of each date

Tags: scala, apache-flink, stream-processing

I am working with scala Stream processing, and I have a list of events, and I am trying to count the occurrences of each date in this format (`dd-mm-yyyy`)

this is my definition of case class:

```
case class Event(prId: Int, author: String, event: String, timestamp: Date)
```

My solution is as follows

```
def CountOccur(events: DataStreaming[Event]): DataStreaming[(String, Int)] = {
    events.map(c => (c.timestamp, 1)).keyBy(x => x._1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).sum(1)
  }
```

this is suppose to return answers like this:

```
2010-09-25,10
2010-09-27,7
.
.
.
```

the problem that I have now is that `timestamp` is of `date format`, but I need `string`.

how can I change that into just the date in string format?

fixed:

this is how you fix this problem:

```
events.map(c => (sdf.format(c.timestamp), 1)).keyBy(x => sdf.format(x._1)).window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(10))
```

but the problem is now it doesnt return anything!!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know flink but I am guessing

```
def CountOccur(events: DataStreaming[Event]): DataStreaming[(String, Int)] = {
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy")

    events.map(c => (sdf.format(c.timestamp), 1)).keyBy(x => x._1).timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)).sum(1)
}
```

You need to remove the second format `sdf.format(x._1)`, it will raise an exception.

Comment: I have already found the answer which works but the final asnwer is not correct!

Comment: then post your answer please